# Как замедлить передвижение персонажа в Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю игру и хочу добавить паутину. Работать она должна как в Minecraft(Объект, сквозь который ты можешь пройти, но он будет тебя замедлять). Гуглил в интернете, ничего не нашёл. Пробовал накидывать на объект Physic Material, меняя трение но максимальное, но оно не работает. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: если ты управляешь персонажем при помощи PlayerController, то меняй ему гравитацию при вхождении в триггер паутины с помощью метода `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`, если не с помощью PlayerController, то все равно можешь менять `gravityScale` у компонента RigidBody

Comment: @Methorn это сработает при условии что он реализовал передвижение через физику.... Что новички обычно не делают.